# How to combine geolocation query with other criteria

Tags: mysql, sql, join, geolocation, inner-join

I am having these two queries:

```
SELECT
          (ACOS(least(1,COS(0.4878295615756141)*COS(-1.4391492410217162)*COS(RADIANS(places.lat))*COS(RADIANS(places.lng))+
          COS(0.4878295615756141)*SIN(-1.4391492410217162)*COS(RADIANS(places.lat))*SIN(RADIANS(places.lng))+
          SIN(0.4878295615756141)*SIN(RADIANS(places.lat))))*3963.1899999999996)
          AS distance, places.* 
FROM `places`  
WHERE ((
          (ACOS(least(1,COS(0.4878295615756141)*COS(-1.4391492410217162)*COS(RADIANS(places.lat))*COS(RADIANS(places.lng))+
          COS(0.4878295615756141)*SIN(-1.4391492410217162)*COS(RADIANS(places.lat))*SIN(RADIANS(places.lng))+
          SIN(0.4878295615756141)*SIN(RADIANS(places.lat))))*3963.1899999999996)
          <= 200.0))
```

and

```
SELECT `companies`.* 
FROM `companies` 
INNER JOIN `service_areas` ON `service_areas`.`company_id` = `companies`.`id` 
WHERE `companies`.`id` IN (1, 3, 6, ...) AND `service_areas`.`state_name` = 'CA'
```

It works like this: the first query finds places within a specified radius. The second query finds all companies that owns the places that are found in the first query.

The part in the second query - `(1, 3, 6, ...)` - in ruby, I fetch all `company_id`'s from places and put them to the second query (`company_id` is an attribute of the `places` table).

I am trying to merge these two queries into only one, because I would like to sort the companies by `distance` (if the closest place to the given point belongs to the "Company A", so this company would be first in the output) and as a result of the query, I am trying to receive:

- companies that have places in the given radius
- places that belongs to the companies and also these places are within the specified radius.

This seems to be kind of out of my league, I am trying to merge these two queries into one, because with two queries, I have to make some operations with Ruby yet (to filter the places) and these operations last from 60-90 seconds...

Thank you guys in advance for your time.

**EDIT:**
I modified the query a bit, here's how it looks:

```
SELECT places.*, companies.*,
       69.0 * HAVERSINE(places.lat, places.lng, 27.950575,-82.45717) AS distance
FROM places 
JOIN companies ON companies.id = places.company_id
JOIN service_areas ON service_areas.company_id = companies.id  
WHERE places.lat BETWEEN 27.950575 - (200.0 / 69.0)
  AND 27.950575 + (200.0 / 69.0)    
  AND places.lng BETWEEN -82.45717 - (200.0 / (69.0 * COS(RADIANS(27.950575))))
  AND -82.45717 + (200.0 / (69.0 * COS(RADIANS(27.950575))))     
  AND companies.id = places.company_id 
AND service_areas.state_name = 'CA'   
ORDER BY distance
```

I also added indexes on `places.lat` and `places.lng` columns. When I ran this query in MySQL console, I got 586 results; the query lasted 1min 22 seconds, when I ran it 2nd time 30s and on the third attempt 18s.

I am just analysing the received results to verify that there's what I need.

**EDIT2:**

When I looked on the fetched results deeper, I found out that the query loads `companies`, but always no `places`. I thought that there are no `places` for a specific search, so I changed cities and so on, but the query still return no `places`.

So I tried to run the query separately, like this:

```
SELECT places.*,
  69.0 * HAVERSINE(places.lat,places.lng, 27.950575,-82.45717) AS distance                                          
FROM places 
WHERE places.lat 
  BETWEEN 27.950575 - (200 / 69.0)
    AND 27.950575 + (200 / 69.0)
    AND places.lng
  BETWEEN -82.45717 - (200 / (69.0 * COS(RADIANS(27.950575))))
    AND -82.45717 + (200 / (69.0 * COS(RADIANS(27.950575))))
```

And this query returns 6,600 places and the query lasted 30 seconds. I've tried to change the order of `JOIN`s in the "big" query in hope that maybe that can cause that no `places` are fetched, but it didn't help, there are still no `places` loaded. I wondering what can cause this issue.

**EDIT 3:**

Trying even this (with leaving out the `WHERE` on `service_areas` table with goal to debug it and to find out why are never returned any `places` by the query):

```
SELECT places.*,
  69.0 * HAVERSINE(places.lat,places.lng, 27.950575,-82.45717) AS distance                                          
FROM places 
JOIN companies ON places.company_id = companies.id
WHERE places.lat 
  BETWEEN 27.950575 - (200 / 69.0)
    AND 27.950575 + (200 / 69.0)
    AND places.lng
  BETWEEN -82.45717 - (200 / (69.0 * COS(RADIANS(27.950575))))
    AND -82.45717 + (200 / (69.0 * COS(RADIANS(27.950575))))
```

The result is over 5,000 unfiltered companies, but still no places there.

Thank you

Comment: That code needs to be cleaned up a little. I can't tell where anything is.

Comment: @padagome I agree that the first query is quite hard to read, but it's because there are some calculation with RADIUS and goniometric functions (not sure how to make better readable). The second one is a "simple" query with JOINs.

Comment: @Padagomez - I tried my best ...

Comment: Is your first query a version of the Spherical Cosine formula (often called the Haversine formula)?  What do the constants in that formula (e.g. `0.4878295615756141`) mean?  How do ypur `places` table and the tables mentioned in your second query relate to one another?

Comment: Thanks @PM77-1 I'll see what I can do from there.

Comment: The first query is `SELECT <formula> As Distance, places.* FROM places WHERE <formula> < 200`

Comment: Does exists a relation between tables `places` and `companies` or between `places` and `services_areas`?

Comment: Was going to ask the same thing. Is there a relation between places and companies?

Comment: Hi guys, I am sorry for my late reply - I was off laptop for a moment. The relations between tables: a `company` has many `places` and every `place` belongs to a `company`. `company` has many `service_areas` and every `service_area` belongs to a `company`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two problems, it seems.

1. Making this query efficient.
2. Using your distance computation to find stuff in your `places` table and relate it to the stuff in your other tables.

It looks like you are using constant values for a particular place   at (in degrees)   27.950575, -82.45717. If that's a location on Zack St in downtown Tampa, Florida, USA, I guessed right at the meaning of your constants.  Let's call those values `latpoint` and `lonpoint`.

The other constant, 3963.19, tells us you're working in miles.  There are 69 miles per degree.

To start solving this problem without drowning in a deluge of math, let's posit the existence of a stored function called

```
 HAVERSINE(lat1,long1, lat2,long2)
```

Such a function can be found here: http://www.plumislandmedia.net/mysql/stored-function-haversine-distance-computation/

That way we can construct our code readably, to convince ourselves we have the right code.

Your first query can be optimized with some nice WHERE clauses:

```
     places.lat BETWEEN latpoint - (200.0 / 69.0)
                    AND latpoint + (200.0 / 69.0)
 AND places.lon BETWEEN lonpoint - (200.0 / (69.0 * COS(RADIANS(latpoint))))
                    AND lonpoint + (200.0 / (69.0 * COS(RADIANS(latpoint))))
```

These clauses carve out a 200-mile bounding box around your starting point. They can use an index on `(lat, lon)` in your table very efficiently.

So, this will be your revised distance-computation query.

```
SELECT places.*,
       69.0 * HAVERSINE(places.lat,places.lon, latpoint,lonpoint) AS distance
  FROM places
 WHERE places.lat BETWEEN latpoint - (200.0 / 69.0)
                      AND latpoint + (200.0 / 69.0)
   AND places.lon BETWEEN lonpoint - (200.0 / (69.0 * COS(RADIANS(latpoint))))
                      AND lonpoint + (200.0 / (69.0 * COS(RADIANS(latpoint)))) 
  ORDER BY distance
  LIMIT 50
```

Because the `WHERE` clause eliminates, hopefully, many rows of the `places` table, this will save tons of time.  See this for a more complete explanation:  http://www.plumislandmedia.net/mysql/haversine-mysql-nearest-loc/

Now that we have the framework of an efficient query ready to go, I'll need to make an assumption.  That is this: you can do this JOIN.

```
 ... places
JOIN companies ON companies.id = places.company_id
```

So, it becomes pretty easy to add that stuff into your query.  **Edited** with information about how the `companies` and `places` tables are related.

```
SELECT places.*, companies.*,
       69.0 * HAVERSINE(places.lat,places.lon, latpoint,lonpoint) AS distance
  FROM places
  JOIN companies ON companies.id = places.company_id
  JOIN service_areas ON companies.id = service_areas.company_id
 WHERE places.lat BETWEEN latpoint - (200.0 / 69.0)
                      AND latpoint + (200.0 / 69.0)
   AND places.lon BETWEEN lonpoint - (200.0 / (69.0 * COS(RADIANS(latpoint))))
                      AND lonpoint + (200.0 / (69.0 * COS(RADIANS(latpoint)))) 
   AND  companies.id IN (1, 3, 6, ...) AND service_areas.state_name = 'CA'
  ORDER BY distance
  LIMIT 50
```

This will find all the companies with service areas **in California** that are within two hundred miles of your `latpoint,lonpoint` location (which happens to be **in Florida**).

A compound index on `places`:  `(company_id, lat, lon)` may improve the performance of this query.

You might want to leave out the `state_name` criterion if you're using a distance criterion to avoid confusion.

Comment: Killer Answer @Ollie Jones *hitting discard on a much inferior solution.*  Extra kudos for all the detailed above and beyond explanation for query and formula optimizations.  I was just going to suggest the second JOIN on the COMPANY and PLACES tables, based on ID... and call it good :-P

Comment: Hello @OllieJones, thank you very much for a very detailed answer, I appreciate it. As I study the solution, the thing is that there's no relation between `places` and `service_areas`. Every company can have many `service_areas` and every `service_area` belongs to a `company`. As I am currently populate the array `(1, 3, 6, ...)` in the query with a script (it's very slow), I wondering if I could use MySQL for this purpose. Playing with the query... Thank you one more time.

Comment: What columns are in `service_areas` and `places`? Maybe they both have postcodes / zip codes? Maybe they have locality names? There may be a way to make the connection.

Comment: `service_areas`: `company_id`, `state_name`. `places`: `company_id`, `zip`, `lat`, `png`. I am trying to run the query, will update the OP with its result in a bit.

Comment: I am a little confused.. you say there is no relationship between places and service_areas... but both have a company_id.  Is the company_id in these different in it's meaning in some way?  At any rate... in case it is helpful... I modified my original SQLFiddle demo to incoprorate @Ollie Jones solution.  It may be useful to debug and/or further experiment on. I believe the tables are structured as you have currently defined them.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/860410/1

Comment: @OllieJones and @Daileyo, thank you guys both. I am playing with the query, testing it and verifying the results. The only thing that worries me is the time needed for processing the query - it crosses 20 seconds nearly every time. I've tried to add index on `places.lat` and `places.lng`, but it doesn't seems to be helping here... Could I ask you  for a tip how to improve this problematic part? Thank you one more time.

Comment: How many rows are in `places`? Are most of them within 200 miles of your test point?  Try a compound index on `places`:  `(company_id, lat, lon)`.

Comment: What happens to the query time if you reduce 200 miles to, let's say, 20 miles?  If it stays high, for some reason your query isn't using your indexes.

Comment: @OllieJones in `places` is 700k rows. I’ve added the compound index and when I run the whole query, the data are fetched now under a second (before 100 miles radius lasted 7 seconds to load), thank you. But I found out that the query doesn’t fetch `places` from the tables, there are always no data loaded from the table `places`. I tried to run separately the `haversine` function and the `where` part in a query and I am getting here results, which is weird. I am posting this update to the OP.

Comment: I think we need to continue working on this problem perhaps by email. My address is in my Stack Overflow profile. (This string of comments is getting out of hand).

Comment: Hello @OllieJones, I contacted you on your email. Thank you